# upload big file to the cloud with php

Tags: php, zend-framework, cloud, rackspace

I'm trying to upload big files to rackspace cloud using Compass API:
http://www.compasswebpublisher.com/php/rackspace-cloudfiles-php-api

It's working fine for small files (jpg) but when the file is more then 100MB the script crash. Well, to be exact, the script just stops.

```
$cf = new Compass_Service_Rackspace_Cloudfiles('myid', 'myApiKey', Compass_Service_Rackspace_Cloudfiles::UK_AUTHURL);
$cf->auth();
set_time_limit(60*60);
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '700M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '700M');
$contents = file_get_contents($path);
$cf->putObject('container/filename', $contents);
```

In a first time I though it was a memory issue, but even with 256M the script is not working.

Any idea why it's not working?

Thanks a lot!

Regards,
Pv

Comment: Make sure it's not timing out by setting the set_time_limit(0);

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what script you're trying to use, but it's probably crashing due to the script timing out unless it's being taken care of.

I wouldn't advise you to use a form to upload a 100 MB file on a regular basis unless it's absolutely necessary and the script is written well to handle limits. That's what FTP is for.

Comment: @gazarsgo: If I were looking to substitute FTP with a secure solution, I'd go with SFTP FWIW. But that's just pedantic when the OP is uploading files via a web form. That said, I agree SFTP would have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As first solution, I would recommend you to pass 0 `set_time_limit` function, because it will make script to be able to run till the end without timeout.

As second solution, I would recommend you to use plupload library for frontend, which will allow you to upload file by chunks. See more about it here http://www.plupload.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use raskcpace cloud API in order to send files to rackspace cloudfiles.

The workflow to uplaod files would be

1. Upload files to your server first.
2. Send the file to rackspace cloud file container from the webserver
3. Delete the file from your webserver or keep it to your choice.

You can use PHP's input:// stream and XMLHttpRequest to uplaod files in chunks to your webserver. More info here http://www.webiny.com/blog/2012/05/07/webiny-file-upload-with-html5-and-ajax-using-php-streams/

You can find rackspace API at https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud